# gpg decryption of multiple subdirectories

Tags: bash, gpg

How do I decrypt files that are stored in cascade subdirectories with `gpg`? Something like a `bash` script:

```
for file in all_subdirs; do
    gpg --passphrase passphrase *.gpg
```

Comment: Use the `find` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options; the first (given the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag):

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.gpg
do
  gpg --passphrase passphrase "$file"
done
```

Alternatively, using the `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.gpg' -exec gpg --passphrase passphrase {} \;
```

Comment: There are second and third level subdirectories to open. The `**/*.gpg` would not work in that case.

Comment: That's exactly what globstar and `**` do -- recurse down subdirectories. Can you show an example of what's not working (in your question)?

Comment: My fault: I did not know the `globstar` and `**` functionality. The script works. Thanks!